# How to get updated redux-toolkit state when component is not re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to delete item in redux toolkit, but don't know how, the remove function only work on screen, i have to press twice to delete the previous one

Here is the reducer

```js
const noteReducer = createSlice({
  name: "note",
  initialState: NoteList,
  reducers: {
    addNote: (state, action: PayloadAction<NoteI>) => {
      const newNote: NoteI = {
        id: new Date(),
        header: action.payload.header,
        note: action.payload.note,
        date: new Date(),
        selectStatus: false,
      };
      state.push(newNote);
    },
    removeNote: (state, action: PayloadAction<NoteI>) => { // 
 ======> Problem here
      return state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id);
    },
    toggleSelect: (state, action: PayloadAction<NoteI>) => {
      return state.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
          return { ...item, selectStatus: !item.selectStatus };
        }
        return item;
      });
    },
    loadDefault: (state) => {
      return state.map((item) => {
        return { ...item, selectStatus: false };
      });
    },
    resetNote: (state) => {
      return (state = []);
    },

    editNote: (state, action: PayloadAction<NoteI>) => {
      return state.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
          return {
            ...item,
            note: action.payload.note,
            header: action.payload.header,
            date: action.payload.date,
          };
        }
        return item;
      });
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchNote.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state = [];
      return state.concat(action.payload);
     
    });
    
  },
});
```

Here is the function where i use it:
**CODE UPDATED**

```js
export default function NoteList(props: noteListI) {
  const { title, note, id, date } = props;
  const data = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.persistedReducer.note);
   useEffect(() => {
    currentDate.current = data;
  }, [data]);
  const removeSelectedNote = () => {
    dispatch(removeNote({ id: id }));
    console.log(data);  ====> still log 4 if i have 4
  };
 console.log(data); // ====> work if i log here but a lots of logs

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onLongPress={() => {
          removeSelectedNote();
          console.log("current", currentDate.current);   ///same
        }}
        // flex
        style={CONTAINER}
        onPress={() =>
          !toggleSelectedButton ? onNavDetail() : setEnableToggle()
        }
      >
        <Note
          note={note}
          header={title}
          date={date}
          id={id}
          selectedStatus={selectedButtonStatus}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I have to press twice to make it work, for example, i have 4 item, when i press one, the item on screen disappears  but the data log still have 4 item, when i click another, it show 3 on console.log but the screen display 2, the redux state is change outside the `return()` but i can't capture the updated state, it work the previous one

Here is a gif to show what going on

[image]

When i press only one item, it change on UI but when i refresh it return same state

[image]

When i click twice or more, it make changes to previous
[image]

**Updated**

The redux-persist code:

```js
const reducer = combineReducers({
  note: noteReducer,
  firebase: authentication,
});
const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  blacklist: [],
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: { persistedReducer, toggle: toggleReducer },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
});

export default store;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export const persistStorageNote = persistStore(store);
```

I also added the useEffect by this, but problem is when i log the changes in function, it remain the same:

[image]

Comment: what is `state.persistedReducer` can you add  `persistedReducer` code as well?

Comment: you are also trying to log `data` before the component re-render from redux. Use a `useEffect` to trigger on `[data]` if you want to know whenever that changes (and there you can `console.log`).

Comment: @shubhamjha of course , i will add it right now

Comment: @Nathan thank for your answer, but how can i store the changes? can i store it in a useState?

Comment: I updated the code, please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is how you can log updated data correctly, as state update is asynchronous it doesn’t change immediately  when you dispatch `removeNote`

```
export default function NoteList(props: noteListI) {
  const { title, note, id, date } = props;
  const data = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.persistedReducer.note);
  // log changed data
   useEffect(() => {
     console.log(data); 
  }, [data]);
  const removeSelectedNote = () => {
    dispatch(removeNote({ id: id }));
  };
 

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onLongPress={() => {
          removeSelectedNote();
        }}
        // flex
        style={CONTAINER}
        onPress={() =>
          !toggleSelectedButton ? onNavDetail() : setEnableToggle()
        }
      >
        <Note
          note={note}
          header={title}
          date={date}
          id={id}
          selectedStatus={selectedButtonStatus}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

about reloading issue, try to close the app and open it like a user of your app would (`minimize the app -> remove the app from recently opened apps -> open app again` ) , instead of reloading the project.